# No instance(s) of type variable(s) V exist so that ExpectedCondition<Boolean> conforms to Function<? super WebDriver, V>

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This compile-time error is thrown:

```
No instance(s) of type variable(s) V exist so that ExpectedCondition<Boolean> 
conforms to Function<? super WebDriver, V>
```

For this code:

```
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return window.value").(true);
        }
    };
new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
    .until(expectation);
```

Whereas, the `ExpectedCondition` conform to `conforms to Function<? super WebDriver, V>`

I'm baffled by the error, any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: What are you expecting `.(true)` to do?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was there is a Guava version 18.0 in the dependency, then changing it back to version 22.0 solved the problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>22.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can put the dependency(selenium-java)  first  in dependencies  and then maven reload